# New trigger pulse from old trigger pulse

Tags: digital-logic

I have an input pulse trigger signal that first triggers 5 times (low/high 0/5v - 1sec interval-) and after that it stays high for 30 sec’s and than goes low again

I need to create a pulse trigger signal out of this trigger that only fires high when the input pulse stays high longer than 1 sec.
It has to skip the short (1 sec interval) pulses. The output trigger stays high as long as the long input (long) pulse stays high.

Is it possible to make such an electronic circuit?

---

I took your suggestion to draw a diagram from the pulses. I measured from the cathode of the LED, this is what I measured.

[image: pulses]

Because my measurements show different values than I expected (negative instead of positive led signal?).
I rethought your circuit in my ‘clumsy logic’ way

With a lot of information from the internet, I more or less figured out your circuit (I could be totally wrong because I am an extreme electronic newbie).

Basically it’s an RC filter with a threshold zener diode. The capacitor never reaches its full load capacity by the 1 sec. interval pulses.
So the used zener does not conduct. When the capacitor receives the 30 sec. pulse, it reaches the full load capacity and
the zener diode starts to conduct. At the end of the circuit the new pulse is shaped by a logic driver.

[image: clumsy circuit]

Please comment

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum or a free design house. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Draw a diagram of your pulses, and what you want. Is counting them ok and triggering on the 5th or does it need to be the long pulse.  What sort of device is generating the pulses and where are they going.

Comment: One second, to what accuracy? This will influence which topologies are available to you. The very simplest I can think of is a single buffer preceded by an RC that crosses the logic threshold at about one second.

Comment: dikkehenk - Hi, (a) Please stop adding your signature to your posts. It breaks [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) site rule. You can see more site rules in the [tour] and [help]. (b) Since you asked the question, the only time you would use the "Your Answer" box, is if you have solved the problem using a technique not described in other answers, *and* don't need further help. Asking for further help in an *answer* turns it into a *question* again. That defeats the whole purpose of separating questions & answers, which is central to the Stack Exchange approach. Thanks.

Comment: It is not a zener, it is a schottky diode. It is used for quick capacitor discharge when input signal become zero to be ready for next pulse.

Answer (score 0):

Simple but not bulletproof is to feed the monostable (555, one shot) with input signal and block it first one second using AND+NOT gates. The two upper inverters just delay signal until monostable fires already. Maybe you will must to delay even more depends on one-shot chip speed. (more NOTs or another delay solution).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very simple and not particularly accurate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXVAnB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: transient]

Probably the biggest sources of timing error will be the capacitor tolerance and uncertainty on the buffer threshold. Discharge curve on the low end will be improved from what I've shown with appropriate use of a low-forward-drop Schottky.

The 109k is found by selecting a large(ish) capacitor of 10 uF, and then solving the exponential discharge via

$$
\frac {-1} {
C \log(1 - V_{th} / V_{cc})
}
\approx 109.137 \text{ k}\Omega
$$